# Does the notation $G \in \mathrm{Grp} \cap T_0$ for a $T_0$ topological group make sense?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

I developed a habit of writing concisely that an object satisfies some properties $A$ and $B$ by writing $x \in A \cap B$ where $A,B$ are the categories of objects satisfying the corresponding properties. A concrete example is for a $T_0$ topological group, writing $G \in \mathrm{Grp} \cap T_0$.

> Does this notation make sense mathematically? is it in use?

Namely, I am not sure if the intersection of categories can be made precise (even assuming the categories are concrete). Can it be justified? should I refrain from using such notation?

Comment: No, it doesn't. A group does not belong to the class of $T_0$ topological spaces. A $T_0$ topological space is not a group. The same group can carry several different structures of topological group. Why not simply say “$G$ is a $T_0$ topological group”?

Comment: People would understanc you, but as egreg points out it doesn't make mathematical sense

Comment: You could write $\mathrm{Grp}(T_0)$ for $T_0$ topological groups are group objects in the category of $T_0$ spaces. Of course, it does not generalize to any pair of properties $A,B$.